# how to reset system

Tags: c++, c, opengl

When I do as below, the coordinate of the pointer is changed. Now how can I reset my coordinate system in order to be `0,0,0` before sketching another object?

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.0f, -500.0f, 1200.0f);
glRotatef(270.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
gluCylinder(quadric,10.0f,10.0f,1000.0f,32,32);
glPopMatrix();
```

I will sketch another object, but current origin system is not `0,0,0`.  I think the point is in the cylinder which is already sketched.

And also, If I sketch another object after the first one, it is also rotated. Why?

Comment: I again suggest you: Start small, begin with drawing a triangle centered on the viewport. Then apply transformations to the triangle. Then chain those transformations. Next you draw two triangles, with independent transformations. Once you got that, you can start with using a transform hierachy.

Comment: By using a matrix stack. glPushMatrix creates a copy of the current matrix and places that on the top of the active stack. glPopMatrix removes the top element. OpenGL uses the topmost element of each matrix stack for its transformations. In fixed function OpenGL there are 4 stacks: GL_PROJECTION, GL_MODELVIEW, GL_TEXTURE and GL_COLOR. If you don't know how a stack works, you first must learn that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type) – Regarding how the OpenGL transformation pipeline is organized and how it works http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Viewing_and_Transformations

Answer (score 1):

`glPushMatrix()` pushes a matrix onto the currently active matrix stack (probably modelview in your case). `glTranslate()`, `glRotate()` etc. work with the top modelview matrix, as does rendering. `glPopMatrix()` removes the top matrix from the stack.

So once you balance out `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()` calls, the stack will be in the same state as when you started.

Comment: if I call rotate in top of the my code, it will rotate all of the object below this call. But I do not want something like this, how can I prevent this sie effect ?

Comment: @user1845897 Do you understand how a stack works? And how a transformation is stored in a matrix?

Comment: is solution related to this ?

Comment: @user1845897: Yes, the solution is related to this.

Comment: @datenwolf you mean I have put much puh operation than pop ?

Comment: @user1845897: What I mean is, that you stop mindlessly fiddling with code and concepts you don't yet understand, grab a textbook and learn on how *stacks* work, the math of *homogenous coordinate transformation* which of course requires the basic gists of *linear algebra*, most importantly vectors of R^n and matrices of R^n×m. This knowledge is crucial if you want to make any progress with OpenGL.

Comment: How about you work yourself through a nice and well written OpenGL tutorial as well: I suggest the one found at http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut

Comment: @datenwolf so why do you just give me answer ? I realy do not understand, ok I will learn, but I want learn my mistake .

Comment: @user1845897: The mistake in your code can not be pinpointed to a single line. The mistake is, that you don't understand the context in which you operate. Oh, I sure could give you a complete working example of what you try to do. But what could you learn from it? From your perspective it would just look like additional random glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix calls mixed in, at some stages of the drawing process. You'd see where, but you'd not understand the *why*. That's your mistake: Assuming, that you just missed some function call or used a wrong parameter, whereas the whole concept if off.

Comment: @datenwolf  1000 *( Thanks for all help especially trying to teach me how to catch fish )

Answer (score 1):

```
glPushMatrix () ;
glTranslatef(0.0f, -500.0f, 1200.0f ) ;
glRotatef ( 270.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
glColor3f ( 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
gluCylinder(quadric,10.0f,10.0f,1000.0f,32,32);
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix () ;
glTranslatef(0.0f, -500.0f, 1200.0f ) ;
glRotatef ( 270.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
glColor3f ( 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
gluCylinder(quadric,10.0f,10.0f,1000.0f,32,32);
glPopMatrix();
```

(This code draws 2 independent objects: one with rotated x-axis, the other one with rotated y-axis)

Every `glPushMatrix()` call needs an correspondending `glPopMatrix()` call. If you want to make 'local' transformations for one object (i.e. translate, rotate) you can simply call `glPushMatrix()`, do your transformation, draw your object and call `glPopMatrix()`. Then your coordinate system is finally untransformed again, and you can draw your next object.

If you don't get that, you could also use `glLoadIdentity()` on your Modelview Matrix after you applied some transformations (to reset all transformations again) - but if you're using transformation related code (i.e. gluLookAt) on your ModelviewMatrix you have to do that again, after every `glLoadIdentity()` call.

```
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0f, -500.0f, 1200.0f ) ;
glRotatef ( 270.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
glColor3f ( 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
gluCylinder(quadric,10.0f,10.0f,1000.0f,32,32);

glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0f, -500.0f, 1200.0f ) ;
glRotatef ( 270.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
glColor3f ( 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
gluCylinder(quadric,10.0f,10.0f,1000.0f,32,32);
```